# Панель снизу (под контентом)

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Не знаю можно ли сдесь размещать ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, но все же. Есть сайт katvin.com, на этом сайте есть блок меню который постоянно находится вверху при прокручивании страницы. Хотелось бы на css сделать точно такой же блок, но только, что бы он был постоянно снизу (под контентом).

Comment: Streletz, Макс Жуков Да спасибо, предоставленные Вами коды действительно работают на обычных сайтах. Но я сие действие хотел применить для панели с адресной строкой браузера mozilla. Т.е. с помощью дополнения расположить панель с адресной строкой внизу браузера, к сожелению этот метод в мозилле не работает. Если есть решения по этому поводу, постите код сюда. Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/position

Fixed - По своему действию это значение близко к absolute, но в отличие от него привязывается к указанной свойствами left, top, right и bottom точке на экране и не меняет своего положения при прокрутке веб-страницы. Браузер Firefox вообще не отображает полосы прокрутки, если положение элемента задано фиксированным, и оно не помещается целиком в окно браузера. В браузере Opera хотя и показываются полосы прокрутки, но они никак не влияют на позицию элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть на стили этого сайта, увидим что блок

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
...
<div>
```

который и содержит в себе меню, имеет css `top: 0`. При изменении `top: 0` на `bottom: 0`вы получите желаемый эффект.

А вообще, задача решается с помощью

```
#selector {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно в CSS `div`'a установить значении `position: fixed` и прижать его к низу. А, чтобы `div` по аналогии с приведённым примером растягивался на всю ширину, можно установить `width: 100%`.

**CSS:**

```
.bottomMenu{    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bottomMenu">
    . . .
</div>
```